# Lists returned in wrong format in nested tree to list-of-lists conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree, iterator

I am trying to write functions to move a tree structure between a list of lists format and a nested dictionary format. The two functions (`paths2tree` and `tree2paths`) are given in the code below. The conversion from a list of lists to the nested tree (`paths2tree` function) works fine but the reverse transformation, (`tree2paths`, built as an iterator), fails to yield the correct lists.

A small bit of code at the end tests the two functions. In the `tree2paths` transformation a print statement suggests that the function is producing the correct lists, but the yield statement appears not to be returning that information to the calling statement. The tree2paths function returns the correct lists, but not in the correct format.

Any idea why the yield statement is not returning the available lists?

```
def paths2tree(paths):
    tree = {}
    for path in paths:
        current_level = tree
        for part in path:
            if part not in current_level:
                current_level[part] = {}
            current_level = current_level[part]     
    return tree


def tree2paths(tree,base=None):
        for branch in tree.keys() : 
            if base is None:
                subbase = [branch]
            else:
                subbase = base+[branch]
            yield subbase
            print subbase
            newbase = list(tree2paths(tree[branch],subbase))
            yield newbase
paths = [['root','boot','bah'],
         ['root','boot'],
         ['root','boot','bad'],
         ['root'],
         ['root','toot'],
         ['root','toot','tah'],
         ['root','toot','tad'],
         ['root','toot','tad','two']
         ]

atree = paths2tree(paths)    
print atree    
newpaths = list(tree2paths(atree))
print newpaths
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
newbase = list(tree2paths(tree[branch],subbase))
yield newbase
```

The problem is that `list(tree2paths(tree[branch],subbase))` is a list of lists, containing your paths. When you just yield that list, you get two elements in your `newbase` list, `['root']` and `[['root', 'toot'], ..., ['root', 'boot', 'bah'], []]]`. What you need to do is iterate though `newbase`, and yield each element:

```
def tree2paths(tree,base=None):
  for branch in tree.keys() : 
        if base is None:
            subbase = [branch]
        else:
            subbase = base+[branch]
        yield subbase
        print subbase
        newbase = list(tree2paths(tree[branch],subbase))
        for i in newbase:
            yield i
```

This produces the expected result of:

```
['root']
['root', 'toot']
['root', 'toot', 'tad']
['root', 'toot', 'tad', 'two']
['root', 'toot', 'tah']
['root', 'boot']
['root', 'boot', 'bad']
['root', 'boot', 'bah']
```

Note that in Python 3.3, you could just write `yield from tree2paths(tree[branch],subbase)`.